# Как передавать аргументы callback aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Пишу бота с помощью библиотеки Aiogram. Столкнулся  со следующим вопросом: я создаю кнопки, при нажатии на которые мне нужно вызвать callback функцию, передав в нее некоторые параметры (в моем случае номер страницы, которую нужно отобразить)

```
back_button    = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text   = '«', callback_data = 'page_no', 
                                            kwargs = {'number': (page_no - 1), 
                                                      'action': action.name,
                                                      'page_size': page_size})
```

После нажатия вызывается следующая функция:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'page_no')
async def change_page(callback_query: CallbackQuery, **kwargs):
```

Но в таком случае отсутствуют параметры, я указал при объявлении кнопки

Как правильно передать параметры в  callback функцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю вам стоит использовать айорамовскую CallbackData ибо передавать таким образом данные как вы невозможно. Разве что через FSM.
Вот пример

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# dun_w это префикс, его можно ловить и стандартным text_startswith=...
cd_walk = CallbackData("dun_w", "action", "floor")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(f"Налево",
                             callback_data=cd_walk.new(
                                 action='1',
                                 floor=2
                             )),
        InlineKeyboardButton(f"Направо",
                             callback_data=cd_walk.new(
                                 action='2',
                                 floor=2
                             ))
    )
    await message.answer("text", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.callback_query_handler(cd_walk.filter())
async def button_press(call: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    action = callback_data.get('action')  # 1 or 2
    floor = callback_data.get('floor')  # 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```